# Implement Paging for Java Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, paging

I have this Map of Java objects which I would like to display as pages into UI:

```
 Map<Integer, CategoryFullDTO> list = new HashMap<>();

 list.put(1, CategoryFullDTO.builder().id(1).title("item 1").build());
 list.put(2, CategoryFullDTO.builder().id(2).title("item 2").build());
 list.put(3, CategoryFullDTO.builder().id(3).title("item 3").build());
```

I create Pages object using:

```
 final Page<Map<Integer, CategoryFullDTO>> page = new PageImpl<>(list);
```

but I get `Cannot infer arguments`

How I can spring the map into lists and get a page by page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `PageImpl` is from the `springframework.data.domain`, then the constructor takes a `List` argument and not a `Map` object as argument.

So you could try

```java
Map<Integer, CategoryFullDTO> map= new HashMap<>();

map.put(1, CategoryFullDTO.builder().id(1).title("item 1").build());
map.put(2, CategoryFullDTO.builder().id(2).title("item 2").build());
map.put(3, CategoryFullDTO.builder().id(3).title("item 3").build());

List<Map<Integer, CategoryFullDTO>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(map);
final Page<Map<Integer, CategoryFullDTO>> page = new PageImpl<>(list);
```

Comment: I want to ask also how I can send the page number(page size) and total items from the angular code?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Since you are using spring, can't it be passed as parameters to a rest end point? (I am not familiar with angular, but all the communication between the UI and backend should happen through an endpoint right?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
final Page<Map> page = new PageImpl(new ArrayList(list.values()));
```